# Creating a cell that updates to new value using multiple factors

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it is possible to create a formula that updates a cell that needs to update based on both numbers and letters or would I need to create a code in VBA.  What I need now is for the following values to update when the information is entered in to a designated cell:
If AA0 is entered in cell A1, then AA1 should populate in cell A2, (I would like to use AA0 all the way through AA9, and then go to AB0, which would then go to AC0 when AB9 is entered, and then if AZ9 is entered go to BA0 (I am hoping I am making since) when any of those values are entered in the cell.  I had tremendous help on here before for a similar question but this involves all three digits/numbers in the cell as a determining factor and I am struggling with a formula for it.  Thank you all in advance for any assistance.

Edited to add:  Everything would just be entered into one cell.  So if someone entered in A1 BC4, A2 would update to BC5.  I wouldn't need a running list, this is to keep track of what the previous value used was.

Edit 2 adding photos for clarity:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You likely don't need VBA for this.  It would help if you show what you already tried, even if it's not fully working.

Comment: put `=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/10)+27,4),2)&MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,10)` in A1 and copy down.

Comment: =IF(RIGHT(D1,1)="Z",LEFT(D1,LEN(D1)-1)+1)&"A",LEFT(D1,LEN(D1)-1)&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(D1,1))+1)),  is what I used when I was using a letter as the last part of the value (i.e. 00a, 00b, etc.) but my new constraints are the reverse (AA1, AB4, etc.).  I tried substituting 9 for Z and 0 for a, but it doesn't help when I need it to roll over to AB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always start at `AA0` put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/10)+27,4),2)&MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,10)
```

[image]

---

If you want the start to be dynamic then put this in A2 and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(MID(A1,2,1) = "Z",RIGHT(A1)="9"),CHAR(CODE(LEFT(A1))+1),LEFT(A1))&IF(AND(MID(A1,2,1) = "Z",RIGHT(A1)="9"),"A",IF(RIGHT(A1)="9",CHAR(CODE(MID(A1,2,1))+1),MID(A1,2,1)))&IF(RIGHT(A1)="9","0",RIGHT(A1)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: My issue is that the value will always be changing and that it will only be entered into one cell:

Comment: Then the second formula will work,  change the references to `A1` to that of the cell in which the user will place the string and it will give the next in the sequence.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you so much!  The second formula is what i needed